# Electron does not play mp3 audio file using <audio> Html5 tag in Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, electron, html5-audio, web-audio-api

**Problem:** I made simple electron project on raspberry-pi, It play an audio file but somehow that cannot play.

**My Efforts**

1. I tried already lots of other audio files.
2. Removed node_modules, nodejs and npm from my *raspberry-pi 3b+* device and reinstall it.
3. I tried also some Electron Versions 9.0.0, 9.3.1, 10.0.0.
4. I tried to update and upgrade my raspberry pi device.
5. I used one simple nodejs file and used a play-sound npm module and play audio file and yes its play but the same code I tried in my electron application did not play.
6. I tried also bellow code snippet with using button click.
7. I also used AudioContext and AudioBuffer to play sound but again failed.

**Electron Versions :** ^9.0.0, ^9.3.1

**Node JS Version :** 10.19.0

**Electron Versions :** 5.8.0

**Device:** Raspberry Pi 3B+

**My Audio Code**

```
var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
audio.volume = 1.0;
setInterval(()=>{
    audio.play();
},1000);
```

**Simple Node JS File With npm module code**

```
var player = new require('play-sound')(opts={});
setInterval(()=>{
    player.play('beep.mp3', function(err){
        console.log('Err :', err);
    });
},1000);
```

**Description:** Above code is perfect working in simple node js but can not work with electron.

**Electron index.js (main process)**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  win.loadFile('index.html');
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

**Electron index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Play</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script>
             var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
             audio.volume = 1.0;
             setInterval(()=>{
               audio.play();
             },1000);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Conclusion:**
I think electron does not have permission to play audio file.

Answer (score 1):

I would start first by having visiting https://chinmay.audio/decodethis/ to see what kinds of audio file your app can play.  Or perhaps you can try uploading the audio file to visiting `codepen.io/janmonschke/pen/OJyMQXd` to see if WebAudio can decode and play the file.

(Sorry, can't post links to codepen without including code.  Insert "http://" for the codepen link above.)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, 
The audio file is decoded properly now what is the next step?

Comment: I think this now depends on how you get beep.mp3.  Isn't local?  Are you running this on your own server?  Check your console logs.  But I don't know much about permissions on Audio tags.